# How do I call a validation on a child update in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have two models, a User and a Post model where they are related with a has-many association (a user has many posts), can I create a validation that that triggers whenever either the User or its associated posts attributes gets changed?

i.e. We want a user to have a validation that is triggered whenever a user attribute gets updated or when one of its posts gets updated/created.

Comment: are you using the `validates` in the user/post model ?

Comment: in the user model

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`validates_associated`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) to trigger the associations on an associated model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_associated :user
end

user = User.create!(name: 'Max')
post = user.posts.new
user.name = ''
post.save! # will trigger a validation error
```

> can I create a validation that that triggers whenever either the User
>   or its associated posts attributes gets changed?

This is not how validations work. Validations are fired when you call `.valid?`, `.save/save!` or `.update/.update!` on the model. This sounds more like a normal callback or an assocation callback or a X&Y problem.

Comment: There is no real reason to use instance variables in the answer. Other than that it look good.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can! You got some special functions related to lifecycle of your models. 
[Check here!](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html)

```
before_create do
  ** whatever you want **
end
```

Comment: the problem is that this will only check if the user model is being updated. however, if the user has multiple levels and one of the levels is changed, before_update within the user model won't detect a change

Comment: One idea that comes into my mind is that you can create 2 functions in each model. If User is updated, you do something then call the function in UserPost model